# Can you use multiple seed phrases on a Ledger Nano hardware wallet?

Tags: private-key, recovery, ledger-nano-s, hardware-wallets

When you're shipped a Leger Nano hardware wallet, you generate that device's native seed phrase (private key) upon opening the device.

Can you additionally recover an existing seed phrase on the device, for example from a Metamask hot wallet, and have both the native and recovered seed phrases active on the same device to access their respective wallet addresses?

Answer (score 1):

No, each Ledger device can only hold one seed phrase at a time. So you can't additionally recover an existing seed phrase on the device, for example from a Metamask hot wallet, and have both the native and recovered seed phrases active on the same device to access their respective wallet addresses.

See: https://www.reddit.com/r/ledgerwallet/comments/r4gctc/can_you_add_2_seed_phrase_wallets_for_1_ledger/

Comment: That thread is a year old with no source. Anything from the official Ledger documentation, i.e. Ledger Nano X?

Comment: This article discussed that Trezor, Ledger and Keepkey hardware wallets can only store one BIP39 recovery seed at a time. https://www.thecryptomerchant.com/blogs/resources/hardware-wallet-recovery-seeds-explained

Comment: Can you recover a Metamask seed phrase on a brand new Ledger device? How about on a Ledger device whose native seed phrase is already loaded in it?

Comment: I think you should look up how Metamask and Ledger create/store their keys. One is a browser wallet & the other is a hardware wallet.

Comment: No, I don't recommend trying to recover a Metamask seed phrase on a brand new or existing Ledger device whose native seed phrase is already loaded in it because it's not safe nor secure. See: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/4787030390301-Should-you-restore-your-Ledger-device-with-your-12-word-secret-recovery-phrase-from-Metamask-?docs=true

Comment: If I buy a new Ledger, and import a seed phrase from an old Ledger instead of generating a new one, what happens to the new Ledger's native seed phrase? Gone forever? Still useable if I format the new device after using the old seed phrase?